# R markdown won't knit to pdf

Tags: r, r-markdown, tex

I am trying to knit my Rmarkdown document to pdf however it keeps coming up with this message:

```
Error: Failed to compile R_Markdown.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex
/r/#debugging for debugging tips.In addition: Warning message:In     
readLines(logfile) : incomplete final line found on     
'R_Markdown.log'Execution halted
```

It is fine when knitting to html and word but not pdf, I have MiKTex installed with the latest updates so what is the problem? I have attached my code below:

````
---
title: 'Maths Skills 2: Recent advances in statistics project'
author: "Jamie Tse"
date: "28 March 2019"
output: pdf_document
---

#Part A: UK fishing Vessels 

The goal of this part of the project is to provide a graphical representation of the geographical distribution of
UK fishing vessels under 10 metres in length.

## Creating a map of the UK using ggmap

I begin by loading the `tidyverse` and `ggmap` packages: 

```{r,eval=FALSE}
library(ggmap)
library(tidyverse)
````

I then found an appropriate bounding box to cover the UK was

```
bbox <- c(-9.05, 48.77, 2.19, 61)
```

Then, using this bounding box I created the map `UKmap` by using the `ggmap()` function:

```
UKmap <- ggmap(get_map(location = bbox, source = "stamen", maptype = "toner"))
```

### Reading in the shipping vessels Data

After creating my map on which to plot the data, I read in the shipping vessels data and saved it to `vessels` using the `read.csv()` function

```
vessels <-  read.csv("Jan_2019_Under_10m_vessel_list.csv")
```

Comment: Go to settings in Miktex and try to change the option of ask me every time to something that auto installs package updates then try again. You can read the log file to find out where the problem is(might be a package).

Comment: Thank you! Changing the Miktex settings worked for me straight away!